# Chart.js: How to display object data types on line graph correctly?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to achieve this exact graph using Graph.js:

[image]

I've reduced the code to this:

```
new Chart($('#myChart'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ['16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00'],

      datasets: [{
        label: 'Users',
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'blue',
        borderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 0,

        data: [{
                x: "16:30",
                y: 775
            }, {
                x: "17:00",
                y: 750
            } ]
      }]

    }
  });
```

1. I can't seem to be adding key-value pairs with keys that don't exist on the horizontal axis.
2. I also want to display the labels on the time axis every 6 columns only, like in the photo. I tried adding empty values on the labels array like this: `['16:00', '','','','','', '17:00', '', ...]`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this I had to skip the labels I didn't want to show, but they had to be on the graph, even though not visible. Here is the code for the Y axis:

```
options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Users'
            },
            gridLines: {
              drawTicks: false
            },
            ticks: {
              min: 400,
              max: 1100,
              stepSize: 50,
              skipRatio: 2,
              callback: function(tick, index, array){
                return (index % 2) ? "" : tick;
              },
              padding: 5
            }
          }]
        }
      }
```

I did the same for the X axis and managed to get an identical graph to the one on the image.